# Inheritance for adding functionality

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have simple question about class inheritance.

Suppose I have class. It has some basic functionalities.
And now I need to use that class, but I need to add some other functionalities that are only specific for that purpose. So my interface of that class will be broken. Basic class is used in many places in the form of which is.

Should I make derived from these basic class? Or better solution?

More details: basic class is text editor with functionalities like importing/exporting to XML, HTML, and controls for navigating. It simply looks like stackoverflow's editor.
And I need to add some methods that are that are only specific for new purpose.

Comment: You will need to give a little more context to get a useful answer. Do you need to access private or protected members? In which way is the interface broken? Why do you hesitate to put your changes into the existing class?

Comment: @userbb: It depends on the context. Base->Derived Derived can have its own functions. When we have to consider Derived as Base, It should work as kind of Base(Liskov substitution principle) and When we are consider it as independent class it can have its own behavior/supporting behavior. So it the choice of the programmer to decide on the design

Answer (score 2):

In C++ [inheritance is (usually) not for code-reuse](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/smalltalk.html#faq-30.4). The alternative is [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), or patterns like [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Is that still true today, especially in C++ with meta-programming, with things like the CRTP?

Comment: I guess you have a point - but I still think that you should be careful with using inheritance for code-reuse, it can quickly lead code that is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use composition I think, just create another class and have this specific class a member, then you can implement any functionality without breaking the interface of the main class and use all the current methods of the main class.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has functions a(), b() and c() and you add f(), g() and h(), without modifying the preconditions and postconditions of a(), b() and c(), your clients will not notice this "change" in the interface - it is just an extension, and it will be compatible with your existing code. In this case you can "just do it".

How will the existing code be impacted by your changes?